# Uploading excel from local machine to sharepoint through SSIS

Tags: sharepoint, ssis

I am trying to upload an excel from a shared folder on network to share-point.
I need to pass credentials to access the SharePoint.

Please suggest how this can be achieved through SSIS package.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i used below complex component to achieve it. See if it suitable to you
https://ssisconnectorsharepointonline.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that.